# Django slow query

Tags: django, performance, django-queryset

This query is really slow and can't run after we upgraded Django 1.8.7 => 1.11.13

```pyhton
  q = WorkReport.objects.filter(
        ~Q(case__customer=session.integration.null_customer),
        ~Q(product = None) | ~Q(work_type__bill_as_product = None),
        ~Q(case = None),
        ~Q(case__casesync__is_closed = True),
        employee__company=session.integration.company, 
        productreportonquotationsync=None,
        productreportonordersync=None,productreportsync=None,
        productreportoncaseasinvoicesync = None,
        approved=True)
```

Comment: What do you mean it can't run? Is there an error you are getting?

Comment: No, the CPU on the staging server just spikes to 99.99%. I have checked in release notes and can't find anything about fetching queryset and it's relationships. It is an integration server, and it just hangs.

Comment: Have you tried using .exclude() rather than all the ~Q?

Comment: This is rather typical for queries with a lot of negations, although here you have a lot of duplicates.

Comment: Yeah, I could imagine. But are there best practices and do you know why Django1.11 is doing this? :)

Comment: @Omar No, I haven't. Why should that work better?